# How to initialize a disk after I append a data disk to VM automatucally?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Based on this doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal I can append a data disk to my windows Azure VMs and initialize the disk manually by login to the VM. Everything works for me.

BUT it is not enough as I want to make the whole process automatually by code.  Could you please give me some code sample or guide about it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ShirazBhaiji provided a helpful doc that will meet your requirement, but there is a new feature that you can run [commands on Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#powershell) directly, no need to enable WinRM. 
Just try the Powershell below :

This is the command to init a data disk in windows :

```
$disks = Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' | sort number

$letters = 70..89 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }
$count = 0
$labels = "data1","data2"

foreach ($disk in $disks) {
    $driveLetter = $letters[$count].ToString()
    $disk | 
    Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru |
    New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter $driveLetter |
    Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel $labels[$count] -Confirm:$false -Force
$count++
}
```

Save it as a .ps1 file.

Use this command to append a disk and run the above command directly :

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name <your VM name> -ResourceGroupName <your vm resource group name>

$dataDiskName =  $vm.Name + '_datadisk1'
$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -SkuName 'Premium_LRS' -Location $vm.Location -CreateOption Empty -DiskSizeGB 128 -Zone 1
$dataDisk1 = New-AzDisk -DiskName $dataDiskName -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName

Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $vm -Name $dataDiskName -CreateOption Attach -ManagedDiskId $dataDisk1.Id -Lun 1

Update-AzVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -VM $vm  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath "<path of the previous .ps1 file>"
```

Result :
[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using powershell, you need to have windows remote management enabled on the VM.

Example scripts can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-ps